# Numpy array loop

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

i'm still fairly new to numpy in python so please go easy on me. I tried the docs but can't really understand it.

I have an array with multiple lists inside. ArrayABC=[[A1 B1 C1] [A2 B2 C2] [A3 B3 C3] ...] so on..

**First question:**
To flatten the list, i do the following:

```
chain = itertools.chain(*ArrayABC.tolist())
Array_ABC=list(chain)
```

Is this the proper way to do it ?

**Second Question:**
So for ArrayABC, i want to find the maximum, minimum and average of A1, A2, A3... I can't seem to find a way to do it without using list and appending A1,A2,A3... B1,B2,B3 and so on... This slows down everything :( What is the proper way to do this ?

Thanks!

Comment: are the missing commas a typo?

Comment: When I print the array, it doesn't have any comma... it looks like this: [[   12.97082329    12.97601938    12.9747138  ..., -99.         -99.
  -99.        ]
[   12.9813199     12.98001671    12.97871304 ..., -99.         -99.
  -99.        ]
[   12.97898579    12.98288298    12.98287821 ..., -99.         -99.
  -99.        ]
..., 
[   12.97687674    12.97687292    12.9731698  ..., -99.         -99.
  -99.        ]
[   12.97086382    12.97206116    12.97205782 ..., -99.         -99.
  -99.        ]
]

Comment: The guts of the array should be separated by commas ArrayABC = [['A1', 'B1', 'C1'], ['A2', 'B2', 'B2'], etc...]

Comment: What about using numpy for this, e.g. to get minimum: `np.min(ArrayABC, axis=0)`

Comment: @Drewdin I'm not sure, I just copied what I had from my output window.

Comment: Printing numpy arrays is different from printing a Python list of lists. The missing commas are apparently normal.

Comment: Underlying your questions is a confusion between `numpy` arrays, and Python lists.  `chain` is a nice tool for flattening lists of lists, but multidimensional arrays have their own 'reshaping' tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are trying to flatten your np array into a single list. You can treat np array as regular python list ( someone please educate, i might not be entire correct )

So you could flatten a list of list like this ::

`[item for sublist in x for item in sublist]`

You can check out this post on making a flat list out of a flat list :

[Making a flat list out of list of lists in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/making-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists-in-python)

Or what Alex suggested :

`np.flatten()`

you can use `np.max()`, `np.sum()` and `np.mean()` for your question two

for instance

```
import numpy as np 
x = np.array([[1,2,3,4],[2,3,4,5]])

to find the max :

max_val = np.max(x, axis=0)
## returns array([2, 2, 3, 4])

min_val = np.min(x, axis=0)
## returns array([1, 2, 3, 4])

mean = np.mean(x, axis=0)
##returns array([ 1.5,  2. ,  3. ,  4. ])
```

Comment: is there a reason why my lists in array has no commas? I can't seem to do the axis=0, it still returns me the whole list for some reasons..

Comment: If there are no commas, it probably mean that you have only 1 element. Can you do a x.shape in your array and see what you get?

Comment: it returns this (28L, 87114L)

Comment: Hi Arbitel, the reason why it appears to not have a comma, I think is because what you have are long integers ( see the L behind), Therefore, when you do a print, instead of printing the super long interger, numpy will only return the first few numbers. To indicate that is not the end, it will not include the comma at the back . It might be misleading to add a comma at the end as this will drive the user thinking that the element is only 10 numbers long.

Comment: See the nearly-simultaneous comment to the question, by Alex above. `>>>a` in the interpreter where a is an np.array will show commas; `print a` will not. See [https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__] regarding this. Evidently the numpy people have taken the liberty of not providing anything that could be a valid Python expression but also not opting for the recommended `<...some useful description...>` format.

Answer (score 1):

Say we have a 5x5 numpy array of ones:

```
>>> a = np.arange(25).reshape((5, 5))
>>> a
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
       [15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
       [20, 21, 22, 23, 24]])
```

To flatten the array:

```
>>> b = a.flatten()
>>> b
array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16,
       17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24])
```

We can directly find the min, max and average of `a`

```
>>> np.amin(a)
0
```

According to the [docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.amin.html#numpy.amin), by default, `np.amin` flattens `a`.

The same goes for max and average:

```
>>> np.amax(a)
24
>>> np.mean(a)
12.0
```